# Firebase - Getting OAuth Credentials to REST Auth

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm working on a project where it was asked for all the authentication to be done in our own backend, that is, without the usage of the Firebase SDK that comes pretty handy. The email/password sign up/sign in are very easy as we pass the email and password but all the other authentication methods, such as Google and Facebook, require postBody which contains OAuth Credentials. How am I able to get that data from the client (which can either be a native app or a react web page)? I've googled and read the Firebase REST Auth page for more info but I didn't find much other than what I already know. I've tried to work around with OAuth Playground from Google but it didn't work as well so I thought that my best chance was asking on SO where people with more experience could answer me.